# Group subscription duration by month and year in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table of subscriptions, storing user id, subscription end date, program id. One user can be subscribed to many programs, but for the scope of the problem the latest date is considered as the end date of the subscription. The goal is to find the number of users whose subscription is ending for each month of each year.  To illustrate it:

```
-------------------------------------------
| user_id | program_id |  end_date        |
-------------------------------------------
|    1    |     1      |  2015-12-10      |
|    1    |     2      |  2017-08-27      |
|    2    |     1      |  2017-09-20      |
|    3    |     2      |  2017-10-01      |
|    2    |     3      |  2017-09-18      |
|    5    |     12     |  2017-10-22      |
|    4    |     3      |  2017-10-10      |
|    3    |     8      |  2018-11-15      |
-------------------------------------------
```

Intermediate result show when will the subscription end for each user (only month is needed):

```
------------------------------
| user_id |   enddate        |
------------------------------
|    1    |   2017-08        |
|    2    |   2017-09        |
|    3    |   2018-11        |
|    4    |   2017-10        |
|    5    |   2017-10        |
------------------------------
```

This was achieved with the query:

```
Select user_id, DATE_FORMAT(max(end_date), '%Y-%m') AS as enddate 
From subscription 
Group by user_id 
Order by end_date desc;
```

The final result must further filter the list, showing only how many users will be left with no subscription in each month, like this:

```
------------------------------
| count   |  month, year     |
------------------------------
|    1    |   2017-08        |
|    1    |   2017-09        |
|    2    |   2017-10        |
|    1    |  2018-11         |
------------------------------
```

This is where I am stuck with no mysql ideas. Iterating through the results and counting is out of the question.

Comment: @strawberry You are right, that was careless data entry on my side. Users are subscribed only once in a program, and then they renew their subscription. I fixed the data in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try arranging the results by the enddate, like this:

```
    select count(user_id), DATE_FORMAT(max_end_date, '%Y-%m')as enddate 
    from (
        select user_id, max(end_date) as max_end_date
        From subscription 
        Group by user_id 
    ) n
    group by enddate
    Order by enddate desc;
```

Comment: No problem for the alias, and I will take a look at the solution. Any reason to do the date formatting in the super query?

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for that. Edited it.

Comment: @LazarusRising It's the difference between formatting 5 rows, or only 4!

Comment: @Strawberry Edited it again. :)

Comment: @Strawberry I understand your point, very good observation. But the formatting is used because I don't need the day information from the end_date when I group these dates into months. If I move it to the super query, it does not seem to group subscription dates into months correctly.

Comment: @LazarusRising It should work fine, as per dev8080's example above!

Answer (score -2):

Try this -

```
Select COUNT(*), DATE_FORMAT(MAX(end_date), '%Y-%m') AS as enddate 
From subscription 
Group by user_id 
Order by end_date desc;
```

Comment: Reason for downvoting.

Comment: The idea is to find the end_date for each user (set A) and then find how many subscriptions will end for each month (group set A based on the month of the date, giving us set B). What your query does, after some syntax cleanup that won't let it work in mysql: Selects one record for each user (the one with the biggest end_date), and formats the date as %Y-%m. So we are left with set A. It does not group this set into months to give us set B. See difference with the accepted answer.